# How do you add a set to DynamoDB with rotary?

Tags: clojure

I'm testing amazons DynamoDB using the rotary client from clojure and I'm having trouble with inserting sets.

if I do for example

```
(put-item aws-cred "MyTbl" {"id" 123 "abc" "something "bcd" 42})
```

it works just fine. I can see the fields in AWS Explore Table and I get it back when I do a

```
(get-item aws-cred "MyTbl" 123)
```

But I can't figure out how to insert a set (DynamoDB supports both string-set and numeric-set). I've verified this by setting properties to sets manually in AWS Explore Tables.

I've tried

```
(put-item aws-cred "MyTbl" {"id" 123 "abc" #{"A" "B"}})

(put-item aws-cred "MyTbl" {"id" 123 "abc" ["A" "B"]})

(put-item aws-cred "MyTbl" {"id" 123 "abc" '("A" "B")})

(put-item aws-cred "MyTbl" {"id" 123 "abc" (java.util.ArrayList. ["A" "B"])})
```

They all succeed but nothing ends up in the table except the id. I tried the last version because when I do a get-item on my manually entered row, the set comes back as that type.

Has anyone managed to do this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There is a [fork of rotary](https://github.com/mrgordon/rotary) that supports the `update-item` functionality offered by the java api. I've used this to insert items to a set:

```
(rotary/update-item cred "MyTbl" "HashKey" {"mysetattribute" [:add #{"newvalue"}]} :return-values "NONE"))
```

Comment: Which version is that? I'm currently trying 0.3.6 but looking at the branches, 0.2.5 seems to be updated in this respect.